VlcControl не становится активным элементом WPF
Пытаюсь добавить элемент VlcControl из LibVLCSharp.WPF, чтобы добавить плеер в приложение, но выдает ошибку. Получается добавить только элемент из VLC.dotnet.WPF, но он не является активным, предлагает проверить совместимость. На сайте NuGet в информации о фреймворках указана версия net, что и у меня в проекте. Такая же история и с LibVLCSharp.WPF, только в этом случае уже даже и добавить не получается. Сильно не бейте, я новичок.






XAML код пишут руками, а не через конструктор перетаскивают элементы. Забудьте вообще про визуальный конструктор студии, точно не для проектах на XAML...  А так, там все просто. 1. Ставите 2 пакета LibVLCSharp (под OS и под WPF). 2. В XAML пишете руками <vlc:VideoView x:Name="VideoView"/>, студия подсветит вам код, жмете на подчеркнутое место и просите добавить нужный namespace. 3. Далее в коде делаете объект MediaPlayer (он попросит создать еще LibVLC). 4. Теперь подписываетесь на событие Loaded элемента VideoView и в нем делаете VideoView.MediaPlayer = mediaPlayer;. Готово.

А да, запуск видео еще... Там вообще все просто: VideoView.MediaPlayer.Play(media); - где media - это созданный объект класса Media (в него надо передать libVLC и Uri на нужное видео). А вообще, у библиотеки отличная документация, даже пример есть. И да, .NET6 устарел, сейчас уже 9 появился, а вы все еще на 6)

ну перетаскивать я и не собирался, а так спасибо

Тогда к чему этот весь вопрос, если не собираетесь? Вы ведь прямым текстом говорите "VlcControl не становится активным элементом WPF", а также скриншот прикладываете, где пытаетесь в компонентах (где всякие кнопки, текстовые поля и пр.) выбрать компонент Vlc, с которым у вас и проблема. На это я вам и сказал - туда вообще не стоит лезть, ибо XAML пишут всегда руками. В любом случае, как и что делать - я написал выше, думаю теперь без труда разберетесь.

думал, что раз он неактивен, то и руками не выйдет, затупил, больше туда и глядеть не буду, только в заблуждение вводит, попробовал, все получилось, еще раз благодарю
